# Swift Combine sink stops receiving values after first error

Tags: swift, error-handling, combine

Im moving my project to Combine from RxSwift
I have a logic where I want publisher to emit event every time I click button. Acrually clicking button executed **pushMe.send()**

```
pushMe
            .print("Debug")
            .flatMap { (res) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> in
                return Future<Bool, Error>.init { closure in
                    closure(.failure(Errors.validationFail))
                }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("Completion received")
            }, receiveValue: { value in
                print("Value = \(value)")
            })
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

The console result

```
Debug: receive value: (true)
Completion received
Debug: receive value: (true)
Debug: receive value: (true)
```

I do not understand why sink receive error only on first event. The rest clicks are ignored.

Comment: This is how publishers work: they stop doing work once they encounter error or completion. This is the same as in RxSwift, was this pattern working in RxSwift?

Comment: Just wrote an example test on RxSwift and found completely the same behaviour. But what is the main approach of dealing with this situation? How f.e. handle that user typed incorrect password multiple time?

Comment: There are several patterns to handle this kind of situation, you should be able to find them on SO, if you can't find any you can always ask a new question.

Answer (score 8):

**What does flatMap do -**

1. Subscribes to the given publisher (let's say XPublisher).
2. Sends the Errors and Output values (not finished event/ completion) emitted
   by XPublisher to the down stream.

So If you handle errors inside the flat map , (which means the publisher inside the flatMap does not emit errors), then flatMap Never sends an error to the down stream.

```swift
pushMe
    .print("Debug")
    .flatMap { (res) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> in //<= here
        return Future<Bool, Error>.init { closure in
            closure(.failure(Errors.validationFail))
        }
        .replaceError(with: false) //<= here
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print("Completion received")
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("Value = \(value)")
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Otherwise you can handle error outside the fatMap. Problem here is that, once an error out whole the subscription / cancellable cancelled. ( in the below example error has replace with a `false` value)

```swift
pushMe
    .print("Debug")
    .flatMap { (res) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> in 
        return Future<Bool, Error>.init { closure in
            closure(.failure(Errors.validationFail))
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .replaceError(with: false) //<= here
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        print("Completion received")
    }, receiveValue: { value in
        print("Value = \(value)")
    })
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

What is happening in the above code.

1. FlatMap `error` outs.
2. replace the error with false (One `false` value will receive Because of this)
3. subscription cancelled because of the error out in the stream.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is that if an error propagates down the pipeline, the entire pipeline is cancelled. Thus, if your Future generates an error, it passes as an error to the Sink and thus the pipeline is cancelled all the way up to the Publisher.

The pattern for preventing this is to deal with the error *inside the FlatMap*. Basically, you've got *two* pipelines here: the one that starts with `pushMe` and the one that starts with Future. Simply don't let the error generated by the Future pipeline "leak" out into the `pushMe` pipeline, and so the `pushMe` pipeline will not be cancelled. Instead, catch the error inside the FlatMap and, if you want to pass something out of it to your Sink, pass out of it some sort of *value* that tells your Sink that there has been a bad input.

A simple solution in your case would be to change the type your FlatMap to `<Bool,Never>`, and pass either `true` or `false` as the Bool to indicate whether validation succeeded in the Future or not.

Or, if it's important to you to pass more detailed information about the error down the pipeline, change the type of your FlatMap to `<Result<Bool,Error>,Never>` and package the error information into the `.failure` case of the Result object.

Comment: (See [my online book](https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsflatmap.html#SECfailingwithoutterminating) for an example of this pattern.)

Answer (score 1):

This is how `Publisher`s work in Combine.

The `Publisher` can either emit values or emit a completion event - once a completion event was emitted, the `Publisher` is finished and it cannot emit any other values or another completion event. If the `Publisher` emits an error, the error is emitted as a `failure` completion, meaning that once an error is emitted, the `Publisher` completes and it cannot emit any more values.

There are several Combine operators designed for handling errors without completing the `Publisher`. Have a look into the [`catch`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/catch) operator for instance.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks all for helping with this question.

Answer of @matt is one of the possible solution.
Another solution is to create new pipeline every time you clicking button.
Im using this approach because I have sequence of steps below failing publisher and Im not able to rely of dummy true/false result further.

```
      Just<String>()
            .sink(receiveValue: { value in
                startProcess()
                        .sink(receiveCompletion: { (completion:
                                Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) in
                            // can handle ALL types of error of pipe line in ONE place
                        }, receiveValue: { (v: P.Output) in
                            // handle correct result           
                        })
            })
            .store(in: &subscriptions)

    func startProcess() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
        Future<Bool, Error>.init { closure in
                    // action 1 
                    closure(.success(true))
                }
                .flatMap { (b: Bool) -> AnyPubilsher<Void, Error> in
                    Future<Bool, Error>.init { closure in
                        // action 2
                        closure(.success(()))
                    }
                }
    }
```

Benefit is that you are able to handle all types of errors in one place if second sink()