# Swift Combine publisher won't trigger in flatMap after finished event

Tags: swift, combine

I'm trying to create a refresh event using CurrentValueSubject while making a network call. So whenever network request fails I can press the button to make the request again, but can't make it work as failure event will terminate publisher and it won't work again.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: TestViewModel = TestViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button("Test", action: viewModel.test)
        Button("Refresh", action: viewModel.refresh)
    }
}

class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var bag = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private let changeSubject = CurrentValueSubject<Void, Never>(())

    func test() {
        changeSubject
            .flatMap { self.networkPublisher }
            .sink(
                receiveCompletion: {
                    switch $0 {
                        case .failure:
                            print("Failure")
                        case .finished:
                            print("Finished")
                    }
                },
                receiveValue: {
                    print("Value: \($0)")
                }
            )
            .store(in: &bag)
    }

    func refresh() {
        changeSubject.send(())
    }

    var networkPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
        var url = URLRequest(url: URLComponents(string: "www.google.com")!.url!)
        url.httpMethod = "GET"
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap { _ -> String in "Result" }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

To fix this I could use `.tryCatch { _ -> Just<String> in Just("Error") }` to catch the error and that would prevent the publisher from terminating. But why it wouldn't work when publisher terminates? And how can I make work after finish event?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64448364/341994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern to not terminate a pipeline on error is to capture the error with a `flatMap`:

```
changeSubject
   .flatMap {
      networkPublisher
         .catch { _ in Empty() }
   }
   .sink {
      print("Value: \($0)")
   }
   .store(in: &bag)
```

As you can see, `.sink` only receives an Output of `String` and an Error of `Never`, because the error is handled fully inside `.flatMap`

Comment: This is pretty much same as I explained in my question that you could do this while using tryCatch. But it's not what I want. I would like to use error instead of never and just, in general, understand why the new instance of network request wouldn't work.

Comment: @kosas, the whole idea of an error is to signal a *completion* of a chain with a failure state, i.e. the subscription (the one stored in `bag`) is done and shouldn't receive any more values. You say "I would like to use error" - use how exactly?

Comment: I thought it's possible to keep publisher alive after an error is emitted similar like .retry() does. In my case, I would like to keep it alive till I remove it from the bag or completion, but not when an error is emitted.

Comment: @kosas, `.retry` resubscribes to upstream. Ok, so your use case can be exactly satisfied with a `Never` failure type... i.e. even if an error occurred, the subscription is still alive, until cancelled

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mapping to a single instance of your publisher, you should be mapping to a new instance.  Your persisted networkPublisher fires off its data task and completes, but you continue mapping the same completed stream in your flatMap.

`var networkPublisher` should be a computed value instead, such that you are returning a new publisher (and a new data task) on every pass.

```
var networkPublisher: AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
        var url = URLRequest(url: URLComponents(string: "www.google.com")!.url!)
        url.httpMethod = "GET"
        return URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .tryMap { _ -> String in "Result" }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Have a look at [this sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publishers/merge/flatmap(maxpublishers:_:)-2z9wm) from Apple.  The data publisher itself is created within the closure of the flatMap, which emphasizes the fact that it is a new instance every time.

Comment: Actually, I had it as a computed variable in my project, but that doesn't work either.