# SwiftUI + Combine - Publisher terminates upon first error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, reactive-programming, combine

I want to perform an API call whenever a user types 3 or more letters into a search field.

I finally got it to work, but unfortunately when I turned off and on the server it turned out that the `Publisher` terminates upon the first error and when user types text into the search field again no API call is made.

I watched the WWDC 2019 videos on `Combine` and read a few blog posts, but it seems that `Combine API` changes quite often, every source does everything differently, and when I tinker around it the compiler often throws useless errors like `Fix: Replace type X with type X` (see screenshot)

[image]

PS: I know I can use `filter` to filter out queries shorter than 3 letters, but I somehow couldn't get the publishers and types to work.. I feel like I am missing something fundamental on `Combine`...

Here is the code:

DictionaryService.swift

```
class DictionaryService {

    func searchMatchesPublisher(_ query: String,
                                inLangSymbol: String,
                                outLangSymbol: String,
                                offset: Int = 0,
                                limit: Int = 20) -> AnyPublisher<[TranslationMatch], Error> {
        
    ...
}
```

DictionarySearchViewModel.swift

```
class DictionarySearchViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var inLang = "de"
    @Published var outLang = "en"
    
    @Published var translationMatches = [TranslationMatch]()
    @Published var text: String = ""
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    init() {
        cancellable = $text
            .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .map { [self] queryText -> AnyPublisher<[TranslationMatch], Error> in
                if queryText.count < 3 {
                    return Future<[TranslationMatch], Error> { promise in
                        promise(.success([TranslationMatch]()))
                    }
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
                } else {
                    return DictionaryService.sharedInstance()
                        .searchMatchesPublisher(queryText, inLangSymbol: self.inLang, outLangSymbol: self.outLang)
                }
            }
            .switchToLatest()
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .assign(to: \.translationMatches, on: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444966/swift-combine-sink-stops-receiving-values-after-first-error ?

Comment: Yeah.. I haven't seen that one. Will go through the examples in your book tomorrow, but to be honest I have stumbled upon this problem here:
https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/04/22/catching-errors-in-combine/ (which suggests to catch the error within the `flatMap`). I tried to use `.replaceError(with: [])` and `catch`, but couldn't get the types right. I just feel like I misunderstand where the types of published values / errors change and how to handle that. Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: I'll add an answer in a moment here...

Comment: As you rightly say, part of the issue is just that you're having trouble getting the types right (and of course the error messages from the compiler are not very helpful). But that's sort of a different matter. Learning to get types right in Combine is something of an art. I give some hints for developing a pipeline in my online tutorial: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/tricksandtips.html

Comment: Just a note: The best Stack Overflow way to show your solution is to give it as an _answer_, not to include it in the _question_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Once an error has been promulgated down a pipeline, the pipeline is completed. It can be completed as a failure, or it can be completed as a single final value if you use `replaceError`, but either way, it's done.

I will illustrate using `flatMap` instead of `map` plus `switchToLatest`, but it's exactly the same principle.

The solution here is to catch or replace the error *inside the `flatMap` closure*, keeping it from percolating down out of the `flatMap`. That way, what is completed is the secondary pipeline inside the `flatMap`, not the overall outer pipeline.

I will demonstrate with a much-reduced schematic of your situation. I have a text field that I'm typing into, and my view controller is its delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

enum Oops : Error { case oops }

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tf: UITextField!
    @Published var currentText = ""
    
    var pipeline : AnyCancellable!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.pipeline = self.$currentText
            .debounce(for: 0.2, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .filter { $0.count > 3 }
            .flatMap { s -> AnyPublisher<String,Never> in
                Future<String,Error> { promise in
                    if Bool.random() {
                        promise(.success(s))
                    } else {
                        promise(.failure(Oops.oops))
                    }
                }
                .replaceError(with: "yoho")
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }, receiveValue: { print($0) })
    }

    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        self.currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've configured the Future in the `.flatMap` to fail *randomly*. But because the failure is replaced *inside* the `.flatMap`, that failure does not cause the overall pipeline to stop working. So as you type and backspace and so on, you will sometimes see the text field text printed in the console and sometimes the `"yoho"` that I'm using to indicate an error, but the pipeline keeps on working regardless.

If you wanted to use `.map` and `.switchToLatest` instead, it would be exactly the same code. Where I have `flatMap` in the above code, we would instead have this:

```
        .map { s -> AnyPublisher<String, Never> in
            Future<String,Error> { promise in
                if Bool.random() {
                    promise(.success(s))
                } else {
                    promise(.failure(Oops.oops))
                }
            }
            .replaceError(with: "yoho")
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .switchToLatest()
```

Comment: Cool! Appreciate the help—I accepted and upvoted your answer :) I got it to work, by using `flatMap` instead of `map and switchToLatest` and making it produce errors of type `Never`. I will include the working code as an edit to the post.

Comment: Actually I am keeping the `map` and `switchToLatest`. I need to get a bit more knowledgable about different operators in `Combine` as they influence a lot what other operators can be applied down the stream based on the published values..

Comment: Yes, as my tutorial explains, `switchToLatest` and `flatMap` are cousins: they both produce a pipeline and set it going. https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsswitchtolatest.html

Comment: But the answer is the same either way: the error needs to be caught somehow in the inner pipeline, whether that is produced by `flatMap` or by `map`, so that it doesn't leak out into the outer pipeline and terminate it.

Comment: Added a rewrite with `map` and `switchToLatest` so you see it's the very same answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Other issues I have run into regarding this piece of code are that 1) after changing my logic to return a successful promise with an empty list when `queryText.count < 3` to the operator `.filter { $0.count >= 3 }` when user types >3 characters and then erases to less than 3 the last result is still presented (instead of an empty list). So I changed it back and it works just fine (I guess it is not the most `Combineish` way).

Comment: 2) I added a `retry(3)` right after `searchMatchesPublisher(queryText, inLangSymbol: self.inLang, outLangSymbol: self.outLang)`, but it seems not to be working. I configured my server to sleep for 10 secs upon receipt of a request and request timeout to 3 secs in Swift. The request times out after 3 secs, but is not retried. I use `Alamofire` to do the requests in Swift.

Comment: I should also add that an alternative solution is to pass down the pipeline a Result object. Your Future (or whatever you've got) calls only `.success`, but what it wraps up in that `.success` is a Result, which itself has both a `.success` and a `.failure`. This has the advantage that you get to _communicate_ the fact that there was an error without actually promulgating an error.

Answer (score 0):

Updated and working code that doesn't terminate the upstream publisher based on matt's answer:

```
init() {
    cancellable = $text
        .debounce(for: .seconds(0.2), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .filter { $0.count >= 3 }
        .removeDuplicates()
        .map { [self] queryText -> AnyPublisher<[TranslationMatch], Never> in
            DictionaryService.sharedInstance()
                .searchMatchesPublisher(queryText, inLangSymbol: self.inLang, outLangSymbol: self.outLang)
                .replaceError(with: [TranslationMatch]())
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .switchToLatest()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .assign(to: \.translationMatches, on: self)
}
```

Comment: Is your "searchMatchesPublisher" sync func or async? I am passing async func to .map {} and it's throwing an error.